# react, express and fetch - send and receive byteArray

Tags: arrays, reactjs, express, fetch-api

Currently I am looking for solution for send/receive `base64` data from `Express server` into my `React app.`
Express server is reading image, converting to `base64` then to `byteArray` for sending it to client `react-app.`

```
  const request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null });
  const base64 = require('base64-js');
```

```
    request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      const buffer = new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
      const byteArray = base64.toByteArray(buffer);
      res.status(200).write(new Buffer(byteArray, 'binary'));
      res.end(undefined, 'binary');
    } else {
      res.status(response.statusCode).send(error.toString());
    }
  });
```

Now how could I read/decode this byteArray in react-app to add this data as image src (using fetch)?

Answer (score 2):

`<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhPQBEAPeoAJos......">` 
you no need to convert base64 to byte array. You can pass it directly to the image source by providing the above syntax. It then displays required image.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert the data being returned. And place it in your `src` attribute in your `img` element.

```
// if image data = { url: 'data:image/gif;xxxxxxxxxxxxx...' }

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { list: [] };
  }

    componentDidMount() {
    fetch('your-api-endpoint', {
      method: 'get',
    })
    .then(function(result) {
            this.setState({ list: result });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
  }
    render() {
    const { list } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
          {
            list && list.length > 0
          list.map((img, index) => (
            <img src={img.url} /> // include it as src
          ))
          :
          'no data'
        }
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)